# Will adding in-app purchases to an app affect users who already bought it?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an app that I am about to add in-app purchases.

My question is this. The app uses a certificate for development and distribution that is used by several other apps of mine, apps that don't have in-app purchase.

As I am adding in-app purchase now, I will have to change this app's APP ID so I can create a provisioning profile for in-app purchases. Will this change affect the app in any way? I mean, Will I be able to upload the new binary with a different provisional profile generated with another AppID? Will old users be able to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app must have the same bundle ID. It's the string in your Info.plist file. If that's left unchanged, users will have no problem upgrading.

If I understood your question correctly, you had a wildcard distribution provisioning profile when you first submitted this app? As long as the new provisioning profile still matches the bundle ID in Info.plist, it's ok.

Comment: yes, I had a wildcard distribution profile. What I need to do now is to create a new AppID and a new developer/distribution profile using this new AppleID and tie that to the old app. My problem is to know if this structural change would affect the users. Obviously I would keep the bundle ID intact. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually a pretty common scenario, no need to worry ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may have created an App ID before we had in-app purchase or push-notification service.  Maybe you didn't think you needed those and wanted to create a suite of similar apps.  Now you want those features.

Say you had an App ID of:

```
com.mycompany.appsuite.*
```

And your app's bundle ID (in the plist and elsewhere) is:

```
com.mycompany.appsuite.mycoolapp
```

In order to be able to do change the App ID for in-app purchase or push-notification, then you should go to the developer.apple.com Provisioning Portal add a new App ID of:

```
com.mycompany.appsuite.mycoolapp
```

This App ID matches your Bundle ID, so your users will not have to repurchase your app, and it will also qualify your app for in-app or push-notification.

Comment: +1 great stuff. Any idea of how this fits into the testing process for in-app purchases? I need to switch to a non-generic App ID, but... do I need to wait until my app is uploaded to test in-app purchases for the existing bundle? Thanks!